# Celleditor for object value Extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm looking for a best solution how to do this.
What I have:

```
// model
Ext.define("User", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "id", type: "int"},
        {name: "name"},
        {name: "description", type: "string"}
    ]
});
// store with data
var oStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "User",
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: {name:"John"}, description: "Fapfapfap"},
        {id: 2, name: {name:"Danny"}, description: "Boobooboo"},
        {id: 3, name: {name: "Tom"}, description: "Tralala"},
        {id: 4, name: {name:"Jane"}, description: "Ololo"},
    ]
});
// and finally I have a grid panel
Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    columns: [
        {dataIndex: "id", header:"ID"},
        {
            dataIndex: "name", 
            header: "Name", 
            renderer: function(value){return value.name;}, 
            editor: "textfield"},
        {dataIndex: "description", header: "Description", flex: 1, editor: "htmleditor"}
    ],
    plugins: [new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({clicksToEdit: 2})],
    store: store,
    renderTo: document.body
});​
```

When I doublecick on a cell I see `[object] Object` in editor's field, and when I enter valid value than I see empty cell in the grid.

So, the question is – how could I setup celleditor to get data not from `record.name` but from `record.name.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `get` and `set` methods on model, so the will support multi-level field names. Below is sample implementation.

```
Ext.define("User", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "id", type: "int"},
        {name: "name"},
        {name: "description", type: "string"}
    ],
    get: function(key) {
        if (Ext.isString(key) && key.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            var parts = key.split('.');
            var result = this.callParent([ parts[0] ]);
            return result[parts[1]];
        }
        return  this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    set: function(key, value) {
        if (Ext.isString(key) && key.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            var parts = key.split('.');
            var result = this.get(parts[0]);
            result[parts[1]] = value;

            this.callParent([ parts[0], result ]);
            return;
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I am not sure if store detects change made to name.name field. If no, you should also probably mark record as dirty.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/dHhbR/2/

Comment: Why not use mapping property to deep link the field like so:   {name: "name", mapping:'name.name'}   - I do this all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

The editor accepts whatever value is provided in the "dataIndex" field of the column. Since "name" is an object, that's what you're getting. After entering a name in the editor, value is equal to a string (not an object) and your renderer is trying to get the name property of the string.

The easiest way to fix this is to make the "name" field of your store a string instead of an object. However, I'm assuming there's a reason you want to do it this way.

The CellEditing plugin has three events it can listen for: beforeedit, edit, and validateedit. You can implement a beforeedit listener to get the "name" object from the column, then get the "name" property of that object and fill the editor with that value. Then on validateedit, get the value from the editor and set the "name" property of the "name" object in the record with that value.

For quick reference, here's the event definition: [CellEditing events](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit)

Comment: +1 I just started typing the exact same thing, I've never seen this "new answer posted" ajax thingy that pops up in the middle of answering

Comment: yes, I thought about this, but I'm trying to avoid unnecessary listeners, the best solution for me is modify the model, so I change it once and will be happy in future.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to modify your User Model object to map the "name" property differently:

```
{name: "name", mapping:'name.name'}
```

then everything else stays the same.

Comment: If I add `mapping: "name.name"` to a model field definition, when I click to edit - an editor will contain `<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="text-align: left; " id="ext-gen1069">Tom</div>` value

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Am I missing something?

Comment: I want to see just original value in editor without any Ext's markup.

Comment: it should work, have you tried removing the unnecessary renderer?

Comment: The data in the store must of correct format. Your data is raw JSON and should be loaded using loadRawData (see http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/HSVj8/) to take advantage of the Model field mappings. If you are loading data from the server just store.load() will do the same thing.